# Problema Raro Mismo codigo diferente resultado?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

Ok no se si esto es un bug , un problema de framework o que.
Estoy haciendo una aplicación que me da la localización de mi cell. 
Todo funciona muy bien en el emulador, estoy usando api 27 oreo 8.1.
La variable status refleja y devuelve el valor de granted de los permisos.
Como se ve en las fotos del emulador en el watch "flecha amarilla".
[image: Emulador api 27]

[image: Emulador api 27]

Pero cuando compilo o uso el xamarin player para correrlo a mi cell samsung s8 oreo 8.0 api 26.
El mismo codigo genera diferente resultado. En ves de devolver los permisos me devuelve un int de 0 y despues en la verificacion 4.

[image: Samsung s8 api 26]

[image: Samsung S8 api 26]

Mismo codigo diferente resultado por tan solo cambiar el device?
No se supone que el api 27 tiene backward?
Que podria estar causando esto?
Estoy buscando en todos lados y no encuentro algo parecido a este problema.
Gracias de antemano por su ayuda!!!!!

Comment: Imagino que estás usando alguna librería externa para gestionar los permisos. Puedes ser [esta](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin)? Si es asi, fíjate en el código que tienes en la sección _In Action_, que difiere en algunas cosas del tuyo

Comment: En el activity lo cambie a : Plugin.CurrentActivity.CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, bundle); no existe el bundle. asi que lo puse asi : Plugin.CurrentActivity.CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this); y mismo problema!